Iterate through a list of file names to create separate PDF output
I would like to iterate through a list of file names and save a separate PDF at each iteration. I was able to set up a loop and create one large PDF output with all the content concatenated. I would like instead to save each file separately.
% quickly build a beamer slide with basic packages and layout
\documentclass{beamer}

% custom font for selected frame
\newcommand{\customframefont}[1]{
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{#1}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{#1}
}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{setframefont}[1]{%
  \customframefont{#1} % for itemize/enumerate
  {#1 % for the text outside itemize/enumerate
  \BODY
  }
  \customframefont{\normalsize}% revert to normal font
}

% tweak for each slide
\def\myFrameTitle{}% empty title by default
\def\fontfactor{\Large}% default font size factor
\def\shrinkfactor{0}% default shrink factor

% looping functions
\usepackage{pgffor}%

% for each file with content, there is a file with tweaking parameters (shrink, size, etc.)
\begin{filecontents*}{FirstFileName.tex}
  \def\fontfactor{\Huge}%
  \def\shrinkfactor{0}%
  \def\myFrameTitle{Test First File}
  \def\myFileContent{FirstFileContent}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{SecondFileName.tex}
  \def\fontfactor{\Huge}%
  \def\shrinkfactor{50}%
  \def\myFrameTitle{Test Second File}
  \def\myFileContent{SecondFileContent}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{FirstFileContent.tex}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Content of FirstFileContent
    \item The font is Huge
    \item The shrink factor is 0
  \end{itemize}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{SecondFileContent.tex}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Content of SecondFileContent
    \item The font is Huge
    \item The shrink factor is 50
  \end{itemize}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}% CREATES ONE BIG FILE WITH ALL CONTENT

\foreach \FileName in {FirstFileName, SecondFileName}{%

  \IfFileExists{\FileName} {%

    \input{\FileName}
    
    %\begin{document}% WOULD LIKE TO START DOCUMENT HERE
    
    \begin{setframefont}{\fontfactor}
      \begin{frame}[shrink=\shrinkfactor]{\myFrameTitle}{}
      \input{\myFileContent}
      \end{frame}
    \end{setframefont}
    
    %\end{document}% WOULD LIKE TO END DOCUMENT HERE

    }{%
            % file does not exist: do nothing!
    }%
}%


\end{document}% END OF ONE BIG FILE WITH ALL CONTENT

Note 1: My MWE could be shortened, but I opted to include some extraneous stuff to customize each file's font as part of an extended test that the loop works well.
Note 2: The motivation behind separating files into two parts is to set up the beamer-specific commands outside of the main content file, so that the main content can be used elsewhere to produce other documents based on the article class.
Note 3: I usually compile with XeLaTeX.
Note 4: I am using pgffor for lack of a better alternative, but I'd be happy to learn about other ways.



If you already have the one big file, you can split the pdf into smaller files.

xelatex is a bad choice for beamer. It can make text in note pages disappear and might result in unusual overlays.

Thanks Sam. I have hundreds of files and I fear it would not be optimal to create one big PDF. Also the frame/page numbers may be off if it isn't cleared after each file is processed? And to split the big PDF, I'd have to know the page numbers for each file.

I have font customizations that would break with PDFLaTeX. Do you recommend LuaLaTex or something else altogether? Thanks.

If you need special fonts, then yes, lualatex.

You can use the tcolorbox package to create independent documents from within the document, but wouldn't it be easier to do this via a shell script or similar?

I don't think this is possible as part of a single compilation. you can trigger additional compilations as part of a single compilation if you compile with unrestricted shell-escape. that's how the externalize library works. (well, it is how it works when it works.) or you can make separate wrappers which input the main file to produce different outputs. or you can compile the pages ans split the PDF, as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggested. that's how memoize works, except memoize automates the process. but you can't have multiple \jobname for one compilation process.

all the tex variants can only make one pdf, so you either need to make a large pdf and split it, or re-run the document multiple times with different settings to make each pdf.

Thank you so much for the feedback. Sounds like I'm looking for a solution involving shell-escape and multiple compilations for each PDF!

why not simply have a separate preamble file then instead of a main document inputting all the others have each of your individual documents \input{preamble} then you naturally get one pdf per file with a simple loop on the commandline such as (in bash) for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i; done

why shell-escape?

shell-escape was mentioned by cfr a few lines above in the comments.

If at all possible I'd like to have all the compiling instructions in the tex file. I use multiple OS and computers and sync the tex files. It always seems like hard work figuring out which terminal commands to use with Windows and which to use with Mac or Linux.

well in some cases to process individual pictures that in the end need to be incorporated into a main document it might help but you simply have lots of separate documents as far as I can see.

you could use bash on all three (that's what I do) or you could use latexmk which would automate it on all three (it's using perl internally)

I have about 100 exercices that I compile into an 'article' type handout and into a 'beamer' type presentation for in-class use.

well the number really doesn't matter, whether you use a shell script or bat file or perl or python or whatever they all trvially let you apply a command to all tex files in turn

Thanks David. If that's the best option, I'll do that, sure!

"What I do" and "what is best"  are not necessarily the same thing, although naturally I think so:-)

Ah, maybe I'll look into a Python solution then!

There are tools which can split pdf according to some conditions, like the start of new section etc. This way you wouldn't have to know page numbers.

Thanks Sam. I'm looking into a Python solution. I didn't realize that creating individual PDF files was another ball game! :-)

I assumed a tex-based solution would be the best way forward, but a chat with samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, cfr, and David Carlisle, convinced me to put together a Python script to perform the iteration. I offer the script below so that the question can be closed and we can all move on with our lives.
    # set cwd
    import os
    from pathlib import Path

    CWD = '/Users/patrickt/workspace/'
    os.chdir(CWD)

    # set list of files
    LST = ['testfile1', 'testfile2']
    LST = [f + '.tex' for f in LST]

    # libraries for compilation
    import sys
    import subprocess

    # delete temp files
    def cleanup(dir:str, files:list[str], extensions:list[str]=['.aux', '.log', '.out', '.synctex.gz', '.nav', '.snm', '.toc']):
        """live dangerously and remove temporary files created during compilation"""
        # initialize a list to store results
        res = []
        for file in files:
            stem = Path(file).stem
            #stem = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]  # before Path()
            for ext in extensions:
                filepath = os.path.join(dir,stem+ext)
                if filepath.endswith(ext):
                    try: 
                        os.remove(filepath)
                        res.append(filepath)
                        print('file '+str(stem)+ext+' in directory '+str(dir)+' deleted!')
                    except:
                        pass
        return res

    # set up the arguments for compilation
    def set_args(filepath:str, texengine:str='xelatex'):
        args = [texengine, '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-output-format=pdf']
        args.append(filepath)
        return args
    # set the arguments for processing | should look like:
    # ARGS = ['xelatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-output-format=pdf', '/Users/patrickt/workspace/testfile.tex'] 
    ARGS = set_args(filepath=CWD+LST[0], texengine='xelatex')

    # process a single file
    def make_file(args:list[str]):
        """set up and execute the mysterious subprocess commands"""
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, _ = p.communicate()
        return output
    # should produce a PDF file from the TEX input:
    make_file(ARGS)


    # process multiple files | set up the arguments
    def make_all_files(dir:str, files:list[str], texengine:str='xelatex'):
        for file in files:
            print('Processing file'+str(file)+'\n...')
            # set up full file path
            filepath = os.path.join(dir, file)
            # set the arguments
            args = set_args(filepath, texengine)
            # check the arguments
            print('Arguments passed to the subprocess:')
            print(args, file=sys.stderr)
            # process the file
            make_file(args)
        # could output a success/failure flag
        return None
    
    # intended to make your life easier, but we all know how that ends
    make_all_files(CWD, LST)

    # be a good chap and clean up after use:
    cleaned = cleanup(CWD, LST)

Only tested once, but worked beautifully that one time...
